# Are "free will" and "volition" interchangeable?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-choice

Example sentence:

> I want to do this of my own **free will/volition**.

Do they mean the same? If so, is one word more formal than the other (e.g. used in everyday speech)?

Comment: In your *exact* context, ***free will*** is far more common, but they mean the same, and I don't think "formal / informal" is particularly relevant here anyway. But there are other contexts, and [this might help](https://withchrist.org/volition.htm): *In philosophy and theology, the terms **free will** and **volition** are often NOT used synonymously, but do convey related ideas.  Unless misused, the term **free will** communicates a sense of **absolute, autonomous, 'libertarian' or unbounded freedom**, whereas **volition** simply implies **power of choice**.*

Comment: I think _free will_ is more likely to be used in everyday language.

Comment: Educated people know what volition means. A large percentage of people would have no idea. Here's a comparison of usage in printed works (volition would be much rarer in conversation). https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=free+will%2C+volition&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfree%20will%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvolition%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score -1):

"Free Will" is the mental concept and discussed what actually it is among scholars such as philosophers.

"Volition" is your innate power to make a choice.

"Free will" seems to be used on one's own mind. However, "Volition" sounds as if you are a vehicle which is driven by a motor.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you a bot!